# Como validar 5 imágenes a la vez antes de insertar el formulario a la base de datos

Tags: php

Hola compañeros  aquí va problema, sucede que estoy construyendo una web de clasificados donde cada quien pueden vender sus productos.

Tengo un formulario el cual lleva títulos, detalles, precio etc. La cosa es que junto al formulario van 5 imágenes las cuales por asuntos de seguridad necesito validar,  me gustaría solo aceptar imágenes tipo jgpe, png y gif y de determinado peso pero no sé como hacerlo.

Aquí les envió mi código a ver si alguien me puede ayudar

```
if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){  



      $imagen =     (random(). $_FILES['imagen']['name']);
      $size = $_FILES['imagen']['size'];
      $type =      ($_FILES['imagen']['type']);

      $imagen2 =   (random().$_FILES['imagen2']['name']);
      $size2 =      $_FILES['imagen2']['size'];
      $type2 =      $_FILES['imagen2']['type'];

      $imagen3 =   (random().$_FILES['imagen3']['name']);
      $imagensize3 =      $_FILES['imagen3']['size'];
      $type3 =      $_FILES['imagen3']['type'];

      $imagen4 =  (random().$_FILES['imagen4']['name']);
      $size4 =      $_FILES['imagen4']['size'];
      $type4 =      $_FILES['imagen4']['type'];


       $imagen5 =  (random().$_FILES['imagen5']['name']);
       $size5 =      $_FILES['imagen5']['size'];
       $type5 =  $_FILES['imagen5']['type'];


      $titulo = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['titulo']);
       $precio = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['precio']);
      $detalles =  mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['detalles']);
      $categoria = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['categoria']);

       $id_usuario =  $_SESSION['id'];
       $usuario =  $_SESSION['usuario'];


    //INSERTAR IMAGENES Y DATOS



  $insertar = "INSERT INTO noticias (imagen,imagen2,imagen3,imagen4,imagen5, titulo,precio,detalles,
  categoria,id_usuario, usuario)

   values('$imagen','$imagen2','$imagen3','$imagen4','$imagen5','$titulo','$precio','$detalles','$categoria','$id_usuario','$usuario')";
  $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar) or die ('Error al insertar registros');



if($resultado){

      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'],"imagenes/".$imagen);
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen2']['tmp_name'],"imagenes/".$imagen2);
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen3']['tmp_name'],"imagenes/".$imagen3);
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen4']['tmp_name'],"imagenes/".$imagen4);
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen5']['tmp_name'],"imagenes/".$imagen5);
   }


  mysqli_close($conexion);
  echo  "<div class='alert alert-info'>" . "Noticia almacenada correcta mente" . "</div>" ;
// header("refresh:5;../index.php"); // redirects image view page after 5 seconds.



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo mi código de un formulario en PHP que hice en 2º ASIR que tengo por aquí, donde exigía a las fotos ser menores de 2mb y tipo .jpg.

```
<?php

$user = $_POST['nuser'];
$pass = $_POST['upass'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
$dni = $_POST['dni'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$volver = "<a href=\"http://localhost/formulario.html\">Volver al formulario</a>";


$obligatorios = array('nuser', 'upass', 'nombre', 'apellidos', 'dni', 'mail');


foreach ($obligatorios as $campo) {
    if (empty($_POST[$campo])) { 
        die('¡ Tienes que rellenar todos los campos ! ' . $volver);
    }
}

if($_FILES["foto"]["size"]>2000000){
    die("¡Esa foto no puede superar 2mb de tamaño!<br/> $volver");}

if($_FILES["foto"]["type"]!="image/jpeg"){
    die("¡La imagen tiene que ser jpeg!<br/> $volver");}


// CONEXIÓN BD      
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","1234"); 
    if($conexion)
        {echo "¡ Conectado a base de datos ! <br/>";}
    else
        {echo "¡ Conexión a base de datos fallida !<br/> $volver";}



// SELECIÓN BD  
mysqli_select_db($conexion, "dbparaphp");

//  INSERCIÓN DE DATOS
$insercion = mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO usuarios 
    (nombre_usuario, contraseña, nombre, apellidos, dni, correo, fecha_alta)
    VALUES ('$user','$pass','$nombre','$apellidos','$dni','$mail',NOW())");
    if($insercion)
        { echo "¡ Inserción de datos correcta ! <br/>";}
    else
        { echo "¡ Inserción de datos fallida !<br/> $volver ";}


// ALMACENAMIENTO DE FOTOS  
$guardafotos = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"],"fotografias/$dni" . ".jpg");
    if($guardafotos)
        { echo "¡ Guardado de foto correcta !";}
    else
        { echo "¡ Guardado de foto fallida !<br/> $volver ";}

var_dump($_FILES); die;
?>
```

Comment: Gracias esta excelente pero como ves debo validar 5 imágenes a la ves, ahí esta mi problema no se como hacerlo

Comment: Prueba a poner 5 campos de selección de imágenes. Ni siquiera sé si funcionará, pero por probar... que no quede :)

Comment: Funciono !!! :DDD. Gracias Tio

Comment: Genial ! De nada :)